# PHP + MySQL while() in a while() only deletes first result from Database

Tags: php, mysql

First off, I know this is wrong. I just don't know a workaround or how to implent it.

This is my code:

```
$description_query = "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE owner = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND id = '".$deletefileid."'";
$description = mysql_query( $description_query, $connection ) or die(mysql_error());

$description_files_query = "SELECT filename FROM documents_files WHERE besitzer = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND vertrag_id = '".$deletefileid."'";
$description_files = mysql_query( $description_files_query, $connection ) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($description_files))
{   
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($description))
    {

        if (!is_dir('./docs/archiv/'.$row1['vertragsnummer'])) {
            mkdir('./docs/archiv/'.$row1['vertragsnummer']);         
        }

        $filename = './docs/'.str_replace("./docs/", "", $value);
        $newfilename = './docs/archiv/'.$row1['vertragsnummer'].'/'.str_replace("./docs/", "", $value);
        rename($filename, $newfilename);

    }

}
```

Now the code first selects info about the entry, then moves the files, but if its more than one file, it moves only the first one in the result.

This is because of the first while as it always selects only one entry and then it stops working from the top.

How would I solve that? really confused.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: you need to do `mysql_data_seek($description, 0)` between whiles

Comment: I want to delete all files associated with a entry in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate to duplicate whiles by doing the join in the database:

```
$description_query = "SELECT * FROM documents d inner join documents_files df on (d.id = df.vertrag_id)  WHERE d.owner = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND d.id = '".$deletefileid."'";
```

Comment: I've seen that somewhere, thank you. My question would be how do I implent it correctly now? $row[''] doesn't work. But thank you for that already!

Comment: I think this hint should be enough to get you started. Please make some efforts. (you'll have one $query and one while with one $row, everything else is pretty much the same). If you cannot get the SQL join work, create a new post to ask further questions about that. Good luck